# Which Okhttp.jar version should I use with retrofit-2.0.1.jar?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using the latest version of Retrofit through Gradle, and it works like a charm (`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'`).

I wanted to use the .jar version, so I can include the library directly inside my app: I downloaded the `retrofit-2.0.1.jar.`

I got an error on `retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory` that was not found anymore. I include the `converter-gson-2.0.1.jar`, but now I have an error with Okhttp at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Okio;
```

I've tried `okhttp-3.0.1.jar` and `okhttp-3.2.0.jar`, but none of them correct the error...

Which .jar should I add to have the retrofit2 without any Gradle/maven dependencies?

My phone is on Android L, I think the problem might come from there.

Regarding all the subjects around that:

- https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/967
- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1519
- https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1475

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use these dependencies in my project:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
```

This pulls in the following modules:

```
okhttp-3.2.0
okio-1.6.0
retrofit-2.0.1
converter-gson-2.0.1
```

Comment: This might sound stupid, but where do you get this list ?

Works fine now, thank you very much ;)

Comment: In Android Studio switch to the "project" view in the project window and open the "External Libraries" entry.

Answer (score 2):

You will also need to include `Gson`:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
```